# Using CallKit (iOS) or ConnectionService (Android) for Tokbox/Opentok application

Tags: android, voip, opentok, callkit, tokbox

I would like to use CallKit (iOS) or ConnectionService (Android) to use the VoIP and have my tokbox video call go through the phone app. Any recommendation/suggestion/link that you can point me to?

I found one reference of Github for iOS, but nothing for Android.
https://github.com/opentok/CallKit

It seemed to me that this would be the best User Experience, but I would like to experienced feedback before dwelling into this

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. Yes, I recommend using the CallKit sample app - we have customers who use it, but I have not used ConnectionService so unfortunately, I'm unable to help there.

Comment: @Manik sorry to hijack, but is there any Android equivalent for this? I've seen ConnectionService mentioned, but also heard it has poor documentation and overall support. Is there a Tokbox sample you could provide me with that uses it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Unfortunately, at this time we don't have any samples with ConnectionService, but I'll be sure to update this message when we add one.